# Column 1 has multiple values with different values in column 2. Need to separate column 2 values using a comma

Tags: python, sql

I have a dataframe `'A'` like this :

```
| Col1 | col2 |
---------------
| a    | 1    |
| b    | 1    |
| a    | 2    |
```

I want to change the dataframe into this. The column 1 values should not be repeated and the column 2 values should be separated with a comma for same value in column 1. I am not sure if it is possible. Any help with a way to do this would be appreciated.

```
| Col1 | col2 |
---------------
| a    | 1, 2 |
| b    | 1    |
```

Comment: do you have some code for this?

Comment: AN answer in python or sql would be appreciated. Use of both together is also fine for me.

Comment: we need some code wrote by you so we can have a start. You didn't even specified what are those values: columns from database, dictionary in python, nested lists....

Comment: There's no real standard SQL way to do this. F.e. MySql has [group_concat](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) But other RDBMS have different functions/tricks.

Comment: I made some changes. Please check

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: dataframe has `groupby()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `DataFrame` so my only idea is to use `.groupby('col1')` to group values. And `for`-loop to convert every `group` to `dictionary` and append to new `DataFrame`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a'],
    'col2': [1, 1, 2],
})

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])

for val, group in df.groupby('col1'):
    row = {'col1': val, 'col2': group['col2'].tolist()}
    new_df = new_df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    
print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
  col1    col2
0    a  [1, 2]
1    b     [1]
```

---

**BTW:**

If you would need to convert back for `new_df` to original `df` then you can use `.explode('col2')`

```py
df = new_df.explode('col2').reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Shorter version with `groupby()`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a'],
    'col2': [1, 1, 2],
})

#series = df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda group: group['col2'].tolist())
series = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list)

#new_df = pd.DataFrame(series).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'col2'})
new_df = series.to_frame('col2').reset_index()


print(new_df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Even shorter version

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a'],
    'col2': [1, 1, 2],
})

new_df = df.groupby('col1').agg(list).reset_index()

print(new_df)
```